# Трансформация значений фрейма даных

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

Есть фрейм с такими значениями:

```
    Month   DayofMonth  DayOfWeek  
1   c-4         c-20           c-3
```

Нужно его переобразовать в такой:

```
     Month  DayofMonth  DayOfWeek  
1     4        20          3
```

То есть, удалит первых два символа:

```
df = df.replace({'Month': df['Month'][2:]})
```

Как делать такое форматирование на данные?

Comment: Как делать такое форматирование на данные?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

```
res = df.replace(r"\D+", "", regex=True)
```

результат:

```
In [169]: res
Out[169]: 
  Month DayofMonth DayOfWeek
1     4         20         3
```